# LARAVEL 5.7: forget() (and except()) still doesn't remove item in Collection

Tags: laravel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgMTc.jpg

Why doesn't `forget()` remove the `created_at` from collection. tried with `except()` doesn't work too

```
$descRequest = request()->descTable;
$wherePage = request()->onPage ?? 1;
$rowsPerPageRequest = request()->rowPerPage ?? 2;
$sortedByRequest = request()->sortBy ?? 'generatednumber_id';

$makeData = Generatenumberid::withCount([
        'generateNumberIdGeneratedNumber as total_generated_number'
    ])
    ->orderBy($sortedByRequest, $descRequest)
    ->paginate($rowsPerPageRequest, ['*'], 'page', $wherePage);

$mapMakeData = $makeData->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $carbonDateString = $item->created_at->format('d F Y');
    $carbonForHuman = $item->created_at->diffForHumans();

    $item->id = $item->id;
    $item->generatednumber_id = $item->generatednumber_id;
    $item->total_generated_number = $item->total_generated_number;
    $item->time_generated = "{$carbonDateString} - {$carbonForHuman}";

    return $item;
});

$collectMap = collect($mapMakeData->all());
$collectMap->forget('created_at');

dd($collectMap->all());
```

**Expected result**

The given column removed from the collection

```
"id" => 39
"generatednumber_id" => "CELLNUMBS-|2019-02-03|-0023"
"updated_at" => "2019-02-03 13:25:01"
"total_generated_number" => 0
"time_generated" => "03 February 2019 - 1 day ago"
```

Comment: I think problem is, that your collection `$collectMap` does not have item with key "created_at". Collection `$collectMap` has only items with keys 0 - 19.
You have to loop through `$collectMap` and use forget for each `Generatenumberid`.

Comment: tried with:
https://paste.laravel.io/2495ab78-b1e9-44b3-8246-95df8fb4a046
got `Call to undefined method App\Generatenumberid::forget()`

Comment: I added an answer. I think you are working with a collection of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you are working with a collection of arrays. `forget()` or `except()` works with Collections only.

So, this should work.

```
//
//
//

$collectMap = collect($mapMakeData->all());
$collectMap->map(function($item) {
    return array_except($item, 'created_at');
});

dd($collectMap->all());
```

Comment: thanks, it works. so how do I do cast it to collection? is there any misuse with collect() i'm using at it?

Comment: There's no issue. `forget()` and `except()` will work with a collection directly. If your collection contains arrays, it won't forget the keys inside of it.

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider marking it as the right one. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: i've tried with:https://paste.laravel.io/b0b32940-0a68-4cc2-b0af-e2cff57dedb4
still not removing the given key

Comment: It's because you are working with a Collection of objects. `forget()` will only work with a single level.